# export 'PickerViewRoot' and export 'MobileDatePicker' not found ... (module has no exports)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, node-modules

I am using `@mui/x-date-pickers` and `@date-io/date-fns` to create a DatePicker.  I am following [this](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/migration-lab/) guide and [this](https://mui.com/x/react-date-pickers/getting-started/) guide on how to get the correct modules installed, but I am presented with the following errors when I import the required modules to render a date picker.

[image: Error Messages]

Here are my imports:

```
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { DatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/DatePicker";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";
```

And the DatePicker:

```
        return (
            <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
                <DatePicker
                    label={title}
                    value={value}
                    onChange={(e) => {
                        setDetails((prev) => {
                            const update = [...prev.fields];
                            update[index] = {
                                ...update[index],
                                Value: e.target.value,
                            };
                            return { ...prev, fields: update };
                        });
                        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
                    }}
                />
            </LocalizationProvider>
        );
```

Comment: Either `import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers";` or `import  AdapterDateFns from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";`

Comment: Unfortunately, your first suggestion results in a ``export 'AdapterDateFns' (imported as 'AdapterDateFns') was not found in '@mui/x-date-pickers'`` error, the the second suggestion results in an ``export 'default' (imported as 'AdapterDateFns') was not found in '@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns'`` error

Comment: Your DatePicker has no `renderInput` property

Comment: ``renderInput`` is now present, but the error messages still persist.  Also, now when I try to input a date into the date picker, I get this ``Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`` error in my ``onChange`` on the line ``Value: e.target.value,``

Comment: Check the [API docs](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/date-picker/#props), onChange is called with the new Date as first argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

delete your node module and tape npm install it work for me